# My swift HTTP POST request is not being processed properly by a PHP api

Tags: swift, http-post

I am trying to get a post request to a PHP api. I need to be able to send the request in Json format. The PHP file collects the post request like so:

```
$postBody = $_POST ['request'];
$signature = $_POST ['signature'];
$rpcRequest = json_decode ( $postBody, true );
```

I need to build a request that is formatted so the api can read my information. I am building my request like so:

```
//Here I am building the request as a string. This string is used to get the signature. 
var params = 
        """
        {"method":"phoneNumberVerificationStart","params":{"number":"\(PhoneNumber)"},"id":1}
        """
//here I build the request by using a dictionary. 
var jsonParams = ["request": ["method": "phoneNumberVerificationStart","id": 1, "params": ["number": "\(PhoneNumber)"] ]] as NSMutableDictionary

let urlString = "******************************"

//below is just hashing the params into sha256
let hashedParams = sha256(request: params)
let signature = hashedParams.hexEncodedString()

//Take what was just hashed and put it into the signature variable
jsonParams["signature"] = signature

//jsonData takes my built dictionary and turns it into a json format to be sent. 
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonParams, options: .prettyPrinted)

guard let requestURL = URL(string:urlString) else{return}
let session = URLSession.shared

// Set up the post request to send to the server. 
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:requestURL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

// Add the jsonData to the body of the http request. This data is json and when printed out in string form it looks like this:
// ( {"request":{"id":1,"method":"phoneNumberVerificationStart","params":{"number":"**********"}},"signature":"2ebdd87bdc66a04419bfd60e7c9b257039bf66dacd1623a1995c971e7cb68ed6"}
//For some odd reason Id shifts up to the front of the json file? 
request.httpBody =  jsonData
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


print(String(data: request.httpBody!, encoding: .utf8)!)


//After this I send the request the server does not understand my post request
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
            (data,respone, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                //print(String(data:myData!,encoding: .utf8)!)
            }
            do{

                print (String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!)


            }
```

I am thinking my problem is the request not being sent as a json object but rather raw data. I am receiving an error from the server that it cannot find the fields 'request' or 'signature'.

Comment: I am not sure how you're trying to parse the data on the PHP side of things. But, your body should have content similar to `request=somerequest&signature=somesignature`. 
This can also be made evident by the content type header. your request says that its content will be sent as an `x-www-form-urlencoded` (A format similar to what I've written above).

Comment: Let me look into how the data is being parsed and I will get back to you, thank you.